# Is there any IDE for mobile development cross platform free for commercial use?

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, development-environment

I'm in need to create a mobile application, but I wanted to make it cross platform (pick the same code and compile to android, ios without much problems). In my searches, I only found frameworks, like PhoneGap, but no IDE free for commercial use. I have only found Visual Studio Community and Xamarin Studio for IDEs, but, as far as I could understand the licenses, I can't use them for free for commercial purpose. Does anyone knows some IDE of IDE + framework I could use for this? What is been used now?

Comment: JetBrains makes the best IDEs on the market.  I'd recommend that you buy a good tool, but if you must have free you can try community editions.  If you're serious about development, buy a good tool.

Comment: I'm searching an IDE for cross platform development, witch I didn't find in their site. I know I should buy, and I would liket to, but the problem is that I live in Brazil and the dollar is way to expensive at the moment to buy a good IDE.

Comment: What does cross platform mean to you?  Multiple mobile phones?  IOS+ Android?  IntelliJ does a terrific job with Android.  IOS is another matter.  Your problem is you want great and free.  Can't be done.  This question should be closed.

Comment: I'm not asking for a great IDE, just something that helps more than just use notepad++ with command line for compiling using PhoneGap. I have found frameworks to make HTML+JavaScript cross platform app (IOS+Android), I'm searching for an IDE to help organize the code.

Comment: No IDE will organize code for you.  That's the developer's job.  Sounds like you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, it does. Maybe what I refer as organize is not what you are thinking. I'm saying like create the base files, organize folders, help with links, help with compilation (like what netbeans does for java). I know java, but I don't think I wouldn't be able to make a bigger java program without the help of an IDE, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I continued searching and here is what I found if anyone else wants to know:

- As Nick Dot Lee, says, there is **[Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)**. It's paid, but there is
  a version for really small projects (Xamarin Starter). It allows you
  to make a code in C# and compile it to Android and iOS.
- **[Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)** allows you to program using HTML5 + CSS + JavaScripy and compile the code to Android, iOS and Windows Phone. As far as I could tell, it's free for non commercial use and `In non-enterprise organizations, up to 5 users` (according to the site). You can also combine it with Xamarin to program using C#, but you need the Xamarin licence.
- The best I have found is **[Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/pt-br/html5/tools)**. It's completely free for any use and you program using HTML5 + CSS + JavaScript. It compile to all 3 mobile platforms, but the compilation is on cloud: the software upload the code to the cloud, it's compiled and them you can download the app. I didn't found anything saying that Intel does anything with the code send to the cloud, but maybe could be a problem to the more paranoid.

Comment: can Intel XDK be used for PhoneGap? Did you get any development enviornment on Cloud and which is for free atleast for individuals or learners.

Comment: I did the research for my company, but we ended up choosing hiring someone to develop to each platform. Since I ended up not it using it, I can't help you much further. About the cloud, depending what you want, you could (as individual) use simply something like Dropbox and for group some version control like GitHub or BitBucket.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Starter is free to use and allows you to build iOS and Android apps (and Windows apps, if used in conjunction with Visual Studio). You can navigate to http://xamarin.com/starter for more information. There is, however, a 128 KB IL size limitation in Xamarin Starter --and on Xamarin you would need to write your app with C#. Xamarin Starter is also compatible with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

Comment: Thanks. I did find Xamarin in my searches, but I didn't notice that there was this starter version I could try. About the Visual Studio community: I have found it on my searches, but don't I need to pay if I want to use it commercially?